# Override variable from abstract class

Tags: vb.net

I need to define a base class that contains the common implementation of logging in my application and create two specific classes LogA and LogB that will use the methods from the base class with a specific variable determining the logger to use.

Now I have the following code:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseLog

  Private Shared _Log As ILog 'This must be overridden in specific classes

  Shared Sub WriteDebug (value As String)

  End Sub

End Class

Public Class LogA
  Inherits BaseLog

  Private Shared _Log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger ("aaaa")

End Class
```

How can I do this?

PS: I don't know how to format code on stackexchange mobile app.

Comment: You have the ILog and WriteDebug methods as **Shared** and yet you want to use inheritance to define the logger.  Can you show us how this would be used?  E.g. using **LogA.WriteDebug("message")** would write to logger "aaaa".  What should **BaseLog.WriteDebug("msg")** do?

Comment: BaseLog is an abstract class, it isn't supposed to do anything alone.

Comment: So there will be a set of loggers (LogA, LogB, etc) and the user of these classes will use the specific one they want.  The references will be hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a field or a Shared member of your base class.  Only a method or property that you declared Overridable can be overridden.  You can a declare a method MustInherit to force a derived class to provide an implementation, you'd consider a GetLogger() function.

In a case like this, were you absolutely want to be sure that the client code hands you a valid logger, the more obvious solution is to add a constructor to your base class:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseLog
    Public Sub New(logger As ILog)
        If logger is Nothing Then 
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("You must provide a logger")
        End If
        _Log = logger
    End Sub
    '' etc..
End Class
```

The client code is now forced to provide you with a valid ILog implementation, the only way they can create an instance of the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your entire spec and what you're trying to achieve; I wonder if the singleton pattern get done what you need to get done.

Instead of `LogB.WriteDebug("Oh noes!")` you would have to do `LogB.GetInstance().WriteDebug("Oh noes!")`. Its not quite as nice, but when you're talking about the base class accessing a member set by a child class it might be the only way to go. This assumes you could use different logs in the same instance of your application.

If you just want to inject different loggers at runtime/startup for the duration (i.e. if you're running in production, development or unit testing), then you may want to look at dependency injection (such as Ninject), or some other form of IOC (inversion of control).

Clearly, this is a more complex problem than it first appears to be! However, it may be that we're stuck looking at it from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an instance property which is implemented in the derived class and returns the shared log variable:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseLog

    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property _Log As ILog

    Shared Sub WriteDebug(value As String)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class LogA
    Inherits BaseLog

    Private Shared log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger("aaaa")

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property _Log As ILog
        Get
            Return log
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```